# swiper react blocks web page scrolling by touch(swipe) on a mobile device

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js, visual-web-developer, react-swiper

I made 3 swipers in my application and only this one doesn't allow me to scroll the site with a swipe, here are the settings that I set for this swiper:

> ```
> <Swiper
>         allowTouchMove={false}
>         effect={'fade'}
>         direction={'vertical'}
>         slidesPerView={1}
>         loop={false}
>         pagination={{
>           clickable: true,
>           el: '.swiper-pagination',
>         }}
>         autoplay={{
>           delay: 5000,
>           disableOnInteraction: false,
>         }}
>         modules={[EffectFade, Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay]}
>         style={{
>           width: '100%',
>           height: `${
>             isSmallScreen
>               ? '350px'
>               : isSmallScreenStyle
>               ? '290px'
>               : isSmallScreenStyleTwo
>               ? '550px'
>               : '700px'
>           }`,
>           marginTop: '20px',
>           display: 'flex',
>           flexDirection: 'row-reverse',
>           position: 'relative',
> }}>
> ```

in swiper I tried to use properties such as:

> 1.touchMoveStopPropagation={true}
> 2.touchStartPreventDefault={false}
> 3.simulateTouch={false}
> 4.className="swiper-no-swiping" - CSS:
> .swiper-no-swiping {
> pointer-events: auto !important;
> }

These methods didn't help.
I hope someone can tell me what's wrong.
I repeat, the problem is scrolling the entire page and not the slides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem, for those who encountered such a problem, here is the reason: if you use the (direction={'vertical'}) swiper property, then for some reason it will not be possible to vertically scroll the page on mobile devices with your fingers, that is, with swipes.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the CSS

```
touch-action: pen-y;
```

property to your .swiper container